# Py4JJavaError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I'm trying to connect pyspark to SQLServer v.16 (reading a table). My spark and pyspark versions are same, I've also downloaded spark mssql server connector (spark-mssql-connector_2.11_2.4-1.0.2.jar) but I don't know what's the right place to store the connector.jar file. It's giving me error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark not found.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.master('local[*]')\
.appName('Connection-Test')\
.config('spark.executor.extraclasspath', 'C:/Spark/spark-3.4.0-bin- hadoop3/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/spark/spark-mssql-connector_2.11_2.4-1.0.2.jar')\
.getOrCreate()
sqlsUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://Server_IP:1433;database=Master'
print("code is here 2")
qryStr = """ (
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table1
) t """
print("code is here 3")
spark.read.format('jdbc')\
.option('url',sqlsUrl)\
.option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark')\
.option('dbtable', qryStr )\
.option("user", "user_name") \
.option("password", "password") \
.load().show()
```

Apache Spark Engine 3.4.0 ,pypsark 3.4.0, Python 3.11 and then downloaded the jar file spark mssql server connector and pasted in my Spark directory. I'm looking to extract the data or reading the data from SQL server and then want to upload it to Share point location.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321485/py4jjavaerror-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sp), you should use `format('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark')`, not `format('jdbc')`, and **not** specify the `driver` option.

Comment: I tried these workarounds but now I'm getting this error:load().show()
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.DefaultSource.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:32)

Comment: BTW: I notice that I copied in the wrong link to the documentation, I meant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16 Your current problem is probably that you use the connector for Spark 2.4, while you're using Spark 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .appName('Connection-Test') \
    .config('spark.jars', 'C:/Spark/Jars/spark-mssql-connector_2.11_2.4-1.0.2.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
sqlsUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://Server_IP:1433;database=Master'

qryStr = """ (
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table1
) t """

spark.read.format('jdbc') \
    .option('url', sqlsUrl) \
    .option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') \
    .option('dbtable', qryStr) \
    .option("user", "user_name") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load().show()
```